# javascript functions differences defining

Tags: javascript

When defining a function, what is the difference between these 2 ways:

1. > function t1() {}
2. > var t2 = function() {}

Is t1 a function itself and t2 a reference to function?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first one is using the function statement, which is equivalent to doing this:

```js
var t1 = function t1() {};
```

It's very similar to your **t2** example, one difference being that **t2** isn't named; It's an anonymous function stored in the **t2** variable.

---

Remember that when using the named function statement *(like **t1**)*, the var declaration is hoisted to the top of the scope.
That's why [this example](http://pastebin.com/H4UGmVSi) works, even though it looks like it's calling the function before the function is defined. The function gets hoisted up above the **sayHello** variable, and that's why it can be used.

The flipside is [this example](http://pastebin.com/ufqXp5ES), showing that the **t2** example doesn't work because the 'foo' function doesn't get hoisted to the top.

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out.

Comment: Javascript does not compile into javascript. I assume you meant these statements are equivalent. They are not - `t1` is hoisted to the top, `t2` isn't. That's an important difference.

Comment: No, the statements aren't equivalent. You misinterpreted me. I was actually just going to add that they are hoisted to the top, also, but I was getting some code together as a small example. You're also right about `t2` not being hoisted. I intended to put examples in there but forgot to when I first answered. So thanks for downvoting, it'll look great after I edit it to be correct.

Comment: You're rude for downvoting, but at least you didn't prevent me from adding more info for future people to see.